# AngularJS : Services are not resolved in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

Angularjs controller unable to resolve the service data.

```
var kattaApp = angular.module('kattaApp', []).controller('kattaController', function($scope, dataFactory) {
    var promise = dataFactory.getResult().then(function(data) {
        return data;
        console.log(data);
    });
    promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.message = data;
        console.log(data.geonames[0].countrycode);
    });
    console.log(" :'( Scope is  not working  " + $scope.message);
});
angular.module('kattaApp').factory('dataFactory', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getResult: getResult
    };

    function getResult() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo').success(function(data, status) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(data) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

In the above code I am trying to set the value for `$scope.message`. When I am calling the service it is returning the data as undefined and after sometime, getting the data and printing in my console.

Please have a look on my [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntvCfG7S1kjnXxrH5lCr)

Comment: your `console.log(data);` will not log anything since it is after `return data;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing result like

```
:'( Scope is  not working  undefined
```

in browser console because you have kept

```
console.log(" :'( Scope is  not working  "+$scope.message);
```

outside then call back put it inside then call back and you will get `$scope.message` with right values.

If you change promise.then to something like this.

```
promise.then(function(data){
     $scope.message = data.geonames[0].countrycode;
         console.log(data.geonames[0].countrycode);
         console.log("$scope.message: "+$scope.message);
  });
```

you will get message like

> $scope.message: MX

Here is updated plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2A4Xc6?p=preview)

**Upadate**

remove $scope from {{scope.message}}

instead use it like

```
<h6>{{ message}}</h6>
```

Comment: Did you observe that I am trying to print {{$scope.message}} value in html but it is not getting that. That is where I have a problem

Comment: As per your comment in DonJuwe is answer. I also want to validate the $scope.message value outside of callback function. Is that possible ??

Comment: Will $scope.$apply() help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 1):

There were several bugs in your code and I got this working, e.g. `<h6>{{ message }}</h6>` instead of `<h6>{{ $scope.message }}</h6>`.

I hope this is what you are looking for:

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/vWfdRqM27U6lsHkhYSVG?p=preview)